# Custom highlighting in definitions

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

Suppose we defined a pattern with custom pattern name provided by user, like

```
Quiet[myCustomPattern@terms_ := f[terms : (_[_, _])..]]
```

for use in further definitions:

```
myTransform@myCustomPattern@localNameForTerms := Reverse /@ {localNameForTerms}
```

However, in definitions like this one, `localNameForTerms` is not by default highlighted the way it would be in case of appearing in explicit Pattern expression. Is it possible to Style it as a properly localized symbol, by putting

```
myCustomPattern -> Composition[myCustomPattern, Style[#, Darker@Darker@Green, Italic] &]
```

somewhere in the low-level notebook representation rules, for example?

Comment: +1 for showing us that you can ignore the warning of patterns appearing on the RHS. Did you find this out yourself? Anyway it is a bit too crazy to be practical I'd say :)

Comment: I guess I found that out myself but it's not really counter-intuitive. There is no real reason to restrict such pattern generation. This is definitely not the first time I place a Quiet to mute a warning of this kind. Maybe I'll post an example of how it could be useful. (If the description won't turn out to be bloated.)

Comment: That would be interesting :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I was checking if the expression is a linear form. Both generators and coefficients are specified as patterns, so it's possible to check if the expression is a linear form w.r.t. f@_ with coefficients matching _Integer | _Rational, for example

Comment: Please before you move on with this, take a step back and reconsider: Is it really constructive if you change your code just to circumvent issues in the highlighter and get a proper colouring? Some very helpful constructs like `Function[, #^2, {Listable}]` are coloured incorrectly. Does this mean I shouldn't use them to circumvent bugs in the highlighter?

Comment: @halirutan I was hoping for a reaction from you on this Q&A :). You are right about `Function` of course. I must say I have once or twice used a `Block` just to highlight some symbols, even though those symbols would never be evaluated in that code segment. I personally wouldn't go so far as to use my crazy code below :P. But I do not see another way to solve the problem, except maybe a custom assignment function with nice `SyntaxInformation`. Note that the colouring is not dependent on any boxes. Also I agree with how the colouring is done in this case by default...

Comment: Really I'm not fond of LHS evaluation of `SetDelayed`. There is no guarantee that a pattern you specify on the LHS will actually be used. For example in `f[ToExpression["x_"]] := x`. Of course we cannot expect from MMA to derive what will happen.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Right, and the *specific* question of Akater can be generalised to: *Is it possible to highlight Mathematica code correctly?* and the answer is *No, not without evaluating every piece of code involved*. Unfortunately, evaluating everything is far too slow for the highlighting process, which should happen instantaneous during typing.

Comment: @halirutan do you have a list of assumptions somewhere, that used that use your IntelliJ IDE have to satisfy? I like the idea of formalising such things.

Comment: @halirutan In case the question was addressed to me: I consider wrong highlighting in Function[, #^2, {Listable}] tolerable, mainly because dash # is a “universal” dummy variable. But I really want to see *arbitrary* localized symbols marked properly.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom 1. Yes, I also suspected halirutan to be interested in this Q&A. :-) 2. Evaluation of SetDelayed's LHS is probably just not explored properly yet, mainly because pattern generation seems to be somewhat discouraged by the environment, IMO.

Comment: @Akater The problem is, that the two situations (Function and your Q) are basically of the same kind for the highlighter. In your case the `localNameForTerms` in the RHS of your `:=` "is bound by/is localized by/references to" the `localNameForTerms` on the LHS of `:=`. In `Function[,#]` the `#` is bound to the outer `Function`. In IDEA this is called *resolving references* and it is all about where a symbol is defined. This concept works for patterns in definitions, `Module/Block/With` localization, `Table`,`Sum`,...

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom No, no such list exists, but you can think of the highlighter in *Mathematica* (and IDEA too) as kind of pattern matcher. If for instance the your `Module` code does not exactly match the form `Module[{..},..]` the highlighting will go wrong. Most basic example is `(Module)[{x,y},x+y]`. From knowing this, you can create your own crazy examples. Unfortunately, some of the crazy highlighter-breakers are not crazy at all, but are used very often. Think for instance about a `Table`, where the iterators don't have the exact form of `{i,..}` but were created like this..

Comment: `Table[iter, Evaluate[Prepend[{1,10},iter]]]` then the highlighting for the local `iter` will not work, although the code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crazyness! Ok so this behaviour relies on something like `x = s_; f[x] := s` behaving like you how you want it to. I must say I am guilty of making crazy definitions myself. Personally I don't like leaving any evaluation on the left hand side up to `SetDelayed` in cases like these. Anyway, you can do the following, but really it becomes only more crazy

```
ClearAll[myCustomPattern, myTransform, f];
Quiet[myCustomPattern[Verbatim[Pattern][patt_, Verbatim[_]]] := 
  f[patt : (_[_, _]) ..]];
myTransform@myCustomPattern@localNameForTerms_ := 
 Reverse /@ {localNameForTerms};
myTransform // Definition
```

This outputs

> ```
> myTransform[f[localNameForTerms:(_[_,_]..)]]:=Reverse/@{localNameForTerms}
> ```

At first I thought `Verbatim` would not be able to do the job, but I guess surrounding `Pattern` with `Verbatim` is a nice trick.

Note that this works correctly even if `localNameForTerms` has a value. This is important, because if you have for example `x=3` and you use instead of `localNameforTerm`, you might not notice that it already had a value due to the green syntax colouring (as opposed to black vs blue).

Comment: Oh yes, it's certainly a satisfying solution. I'll accept if no alternatives show up, thank you. Unfortunately myCustomPattern@localNameForTerms_ would then generate a pattern with localNameForTerms standing for BlankSequence while the mark-up corresponds to Blank, but that seems to be a relatively minor drawback.

Comment: …and I think it's even possible to manage Blank vs BlankSeqeunce behaviour automatically, so there are no drawbacks, after all.